# Error using Google App Engine cloudshell to upload Python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use appcfg to upload my helloworld app on GCloud using GAE. According to Google's own quickstarter site, the syntax is: 
*appcfg.py -A YOUR_PROJECT_ID_ -V v1 update helloworld/*

So I did:
*appcfg.py -A project_name_123456 -V v1 update c:/users/user/helloworld/*

Which makes this error:
*"appcfg.py: error: Not a directory: C:/users/user/helloworld"*

What am I doing wrong? I have the app.yaml file in C:/users/user/helloworld, and I've tried lots of different things. Thanks

Comment: Try '\' instead of '/' as path delimiter: `C:\users\user\helloworld`

Comment: I've tried both ways (I think / is correct here in the GCloud shell though)

Comment: How about directly specifying the `app.yaml` file instead of its dir? While there - the app name and version should normally be in your `app.yaml` file, you don't need to specify them on the cmdline unless you're overwriting them. Just trying to keep things simple/less error prone... It'd boil down to `appcfg.py update c:/users/user/helloworld/app.yaml`

Comment: Google's quickstarter says to upload the whole folder. What I've figured out was that this should be typed in the local command line, not in Google cloud shell.

Comment: The folder containing the `.yaml` file is automatically considered as the respective app/module folder and uploaded. Specifying the directory only works for single-module apps, for multi-module apps you *have to* specify the `.yaml` files, which may or may not be in the same dir - specifying just a dir is ambiguous. Anyways, that's for later. You should add an answer and accept it to not leave the question unanswered and possibly help others.